# How to change boolean from False to True using functions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been coding a text based RPG, to become familiar with classes, functions, and modules, and how they interact and relate to each other.  Currently, I have a room, really a function, that works a bit like a hub-type area to interconnect 3 different rooms.  I'm going to post a bit of code here, and elaborate more on my problem after this block of code.  The code looks a little like this (simplified to show my point):

```
def room_hub():
    movement = raw_input("[W] for North, [D] for East, and [A] for West:").lower()
    if movement == 'd':
        if room_E_bool == False:
             print "You have moved East! "
             room_East()

        elif room_E_bool == True:
             print "You have already been to that room! "
             room_hub()

def room_East():
    print "There's treasure here!"
    treasure = raw_input("Press [Y] to collect treasure! ").lower()
    if treasure == 'y':
         room_E_bool = True
         print "You have collected treasure!"
         print "Returning to the hub area!"
         room_hub()
    else:
        print "Not a valid command!"
        room_hub()
```

The idea is that I want a boolean value changed when the user runs through a function.  That way, when they return to the hub like area, they won't be allowed to revisit a certain room.  Of course, this may not be a very good method of doing something like this, and if that's the case, I'd like to be presented with other solutions to this issue of restricting players from certain rooms once they visited them.

I've tried having the boolean as a global variable, listing it at the top of the Python file, so that the hub function can reference the boolean value to determine what options are available.  However, it seems both this method of a global boolean, and a localized one inside of a function, doesn't work well in terms of declaring a new boolean value.

Is there a way I can use booleans to determine whether or not a player has ran through a certain function, or are there better means of doing this?

EDIT:
Here is the chunck of code I am referencing.  I moved the boolean to change values after the player types [D]; however, it still cycles through and allows them back into the room.

```
def area_1_c(self):
    global dungeon_area_1
    dungeon = dungeon_area_1()
    print "You step into a hub like area."
    print "There are three ways to go: "
    print "North, east and west. "
    print ' '
    print "You can now also view your inventory anytime by pressing [I] when prompted for a choice. "
    print ' '
    print "Press [W] for North, [D] for East, [A] for West, [I] to view inventory."
    input = raw_input("What is your next choice?: ").lower()
    while input:
        if input == 'w':
            dungeon.area_1_f()
            print " "

        elif input == 'd':
            bool = False
            if bool == True:
                print "You have already explored this area. "
                print ' '
                input = raw_input("What is your next choice?: ").lower()
                continue
            else:
                bool = True
                print "You walk towards the east. "
                print ' '
                dungeon.area_1_d()

        elif input == 'a':
            dungeon.area_1_e()

        elif input == 'i':
            print inventory
            print ' '
            input = raw_input("What is your choice?: ").lower()
            continue    

        else:
            return

def area_1_d(self):
    print "You push open an iron door, behind it lies a room decorated in vines and insects."
    print "Out of the corner of your eye, you notice a chest.  You walk towards it. "
    input = raw_input("Press [Y] to open chest.: ").lower()
    if input == 'y':
        x = random.randint(1, 20)
        global dungeon_area_1
        if x >= 10:
            print "You open the chest and reveal 20 gold!"
            inventory["Gold"] = (inventory["Gold"] + 20)
            print "You turn around and walk out the door, back to the hub area. "
            dungeon = dungeon_area_1()
            dungeon.area_1_c()

        elif x < 10:
            print "You open the chest and reveal 5 gold!"
            inventory["Gold"] = (inventory["Gold"] + 5)
            print "You turn around and walk out the door, back to the hub area. "
            dungeon = dungeon_area_1()
            dungeon.area_1_c()
```

Sorry if the code is messy and what not.  It is still far, far away from being finished.

Comment: Why not just set the value in `room_hub` after you call the room function?

Comment: Eg, after `if room_e_bool: room_e_bool = True` (Also, you don't need to compare to True/False, you can just do `if variable`).

Comment: or just room_e_bool = !room_e_bool

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN Well, no. That will allow them back in the room the second time they try to enter.

Comment: @MorganThrapp yea you are right.

Comment: If you want to modify a global variable from within a function, you have to explicitly declare it within the function, e.g. `global room_E_bool`.  You only need to do this if you want to change it.  Otherwise, assigning to it will create a local variable.

Comment: this would be the perfect example to use class :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.  Thanks for the help, especially Tom Karzes above.  I changed the boolean variable to be global, and then noting `global bool`, I was able to change the global variable, based of the user's choice of [D], by saying:

`elif input == 'd':
    global bool
    bool = True`

It now works the way I want it to.